# how to output metrics of both train and valid with fastai

Tags: validation, metrics, training-data, fast-ai

I'm trying to use CSVLogger to log metrics during training. Although I see loss of both train and valid, I see only the metrics (e.g. accuracy) of train in the saved log file at each epoch:

[image]

Howe can I extract the metrics of valid data as well?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the value of the metrics during training on the validation set as well as the training set, you have to add the Recorder callback with `Recorder(train_metrics=True, valid_metrics=True)`.

**However**, your learner most likely already has a recorder callback by default, in which case adding the `Recorder` triggers a bug which destroys the logging of metrics. (Some rows will have too many values and others won't have enough. Metrics will be logged in the wrong row.)

In that case you will want to do:

```py
learn = vision_learner(...)


learn.recorder.train_metrics = True
learn.recorder.valid_metrics = True
```